# TypeScript/Angular 2 - call a function after another completes

Tags: asynchronous, angular, typescript

I have two functions that I would like to call, but I only want to call the second one after the first one completes. How do I go about doing that?

**First** function:

```
getDirectorySubfolders(node: any) {
    console.log('Home:getDirectorySubfolders() entered...');

    this._sdiService.getDirectoriesAtPath("Desktop")
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.nodeChildren = res;
        });
}
```

**Second** function:

```
getChildren(node: any) {
   console.log('Home:getChildren entered..');
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
   {
       setTimeout(() => resolve(this.nodeChildren.map((c) =>
       {
           return Object.assign({}, c, {});
       })), 1000);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two simple ways to call your second function after first one is finished - you can do it under `this.nodeChildren = res;` or use finish parameter `()`:

```
getDirectorySubfolders(node: any) {
    console.log('Home:getDirectorySubfolders() entered...');

    this._sdiService.getDirectoriesAtPath("Desktop")
        .subscribe(
         res => {
             this.nodeChildren = res;
             this.getChildren(); <-- here
         },
         err => {
             console.log(err);
         },
         () => {
             this.getChildren(); <-- or here
         });
}
```

When you call `getDirectorySubfolders()` function, `getChildren()` will be called after completion of  `getDirectorySubfolders()`. Keep in mind that if you use finish parameter, the function will get called even if error occurs.

Comment: Hey @Stefan Svrkota, I tried your solution and it looks like, in the most recent version of angular, you are passing in an error method for the `()` section, not a `complete` method. you need to add something like this: `this._sdiService.getDirectoriesAtPath("Desktop")
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.nodeChildren = res;
            this.getChildren(); <-- here
        }, null, // doesn't have to be null, just another parameter
        () => {
            this.getChildren(); <-- or here
        });`

Comment: @Ethan That's true, I edited my answer so it doesn't create any confusion for the further readers. Thank you so much for letting me know!

Comment: you are so welcome! Happy to help, this post helped me make a step in the right direction :D